# Spark Label Truncating Issue

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, label, truncate

I have a Flex spark Label component with properties width=125 and maxDisplayedLines=1. This successfully truncates the text when it is too long to display, however if brackets are involved then the text is truncated in a way I do not want.

For example I set the text to "You (chinchiheather)" and it displays "You(..." never displaying any part of the text in brackets unless it can display all of it. I would prefer "You (chinchi..." than what I am being given. Is there some property I can set so that brackets are not treated specially, or does anyone know of some other way around this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Label` has a `lineBreak` style that you can use to control word wrapping. It also seems to apply to truncation. If you set the `lineBreak` style equal to "explicit", the text be truncated at the point it no longer fits, and not after an open parentheses.

The default value is for this style is "toFit".

```
<s:Label lineBreak="explicit" />
```

Or

```
var label:Label = new Label();
label.setStyle("lineBreak", "explicit");
```